# SQL Group by sum

Tags: sql

```
id  group  sal
----------------
3    a      1000
3    b      500
2    c      2000
```

I need the result like this.

```
id sum
-------
3   1500
2   2000
```

Comment: take some time and improve your question please, have you already tried to find the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id
     , SUM(sal) 'sum'
FROM   yourtablename
GROUP BY id;
```

I think you're looking for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could `group by` the `id` and sum the `sal`:

```
SELECT   id, SUM(sal)
FROM     sometable
GROUP BY id
```